# Why Multiple check Radio button . I want To Single Checked in from

Tags: php, jquery, html, checkbox

My Code I want to single checked. but It is multiple check . How can i single selection in this types of situation ?

This is my code

```
<?php
$i=5;

for($i=1; $i<6; $i++)
{
   ?>
<form name="form" id="myform" class="frmclass">
   <input type="radio" name="rdo" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $i; ?> <br>
</form>

<?php }

?>
```

Comment: So where is your code. Debugging your code for you is so much easier **if we can see it**

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: take form tag out of loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created 5 seperate forms. Place the `<form>` and `</form>` tags outside the loop

```
<?php
$i=5;
?>
<form name="form" id="myform" class="frmclass">

<?php
for($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {
{
?>
   <input type="radio" name="rdo" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $i; ?> <br>
<?php 
}
?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place your form outside of loop. like below..

```
<form name="form" id="myform" class="frmclass">
<?php
$i=5;
for($i=1; $i<6; $i++)
{
?>
<input type="radio" name="rdo" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"> <?php echo $i; ?> <br>
<?php 
}
?>
</form>
```